# How to align <td> with digits inside to the right, jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, alignment

i have a table(s) with different dynamic-generated content inside.
How can i do that all  with only numbers inside will have text-align to the right?

Well, i know how to add css to some element, the question is how to get only tds with digits

Thank you!

Comment: You want table cells that contain *only* numbers to be `text-align: right`?

Comment: exatcly, David, and others are unchanged

Comment: and by 'digits' i also mean contents like that: '32 784,63'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) option:

```
$('td').filter(function() {
  return this.innerHTML.match(/^[0-9\s\.,]+$/);
}).css('text-align','right');
```

This will match "123", "12 3", "12.3" and "12,3" but not "abc", "abc123", etc.

Comment: and what changes should be if there is `&nbsp;` symbol instead of spacebar?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can match either `\s` or `&nbsp;` in this way (without also match e.g. "12nb"), but this will work: `this.innerHTML.replace('&nbsp;','').match(/^[0-9\s\.,]+$/);`

Answer (score 2):

If you want a jQuery-ish solution, one way is to use a custom selector:

```
$.expr[':'].isNumeric = function(obj){
  return !isNAN( $(obj).text() );
};
```

And then:

```
$('td:isNumeric').addClass('numeric');
```

Which assumes the style:

```
td.numeric { text-align: right; }
```

...or if you prefer:

```
$('td:isNumeric').css('text-align','right');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not real clear but you can align-right in any cell like this:

```
<td align="right">123</td>
```

Comment: He needs a jQuery selector to target table cells containing only numbers.

Comment: The way I read it -and I'm taking a huge intuitive leap- is that the data *in* the cells is dynamically generated. So he needs JS/jQuery to find those cells with only numbers and then `text-align: right` them. But I'm mostly guessing, unfortunately.

Comment: the problem is, that i dont know if the cell contains only numbers, thats why i need js/jQuery solution

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest some jquery, I've mocked up on [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/uwaci3/edit).

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $("td").each(function(index, item){    

        if(isNaN($(item).text()) == false){
            $(item).addClass("match");
        } 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Then you might want to head over to [the Editing Help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to have a quick look-see =)

Answer (score 0):

A better variation for Alec's wonderful answer, is

```
$('td').filter(function () {
    return this.innerText.match(/^[-?0-9\s\.,]+$/);
}).css('text-align', 'right');
```

This catches also negative numbers and will much the cell's textual content rather than the html content which fails in cases like

```
<td>
<div>1.49</div>
</td>
```